# How do I setup a second component with a UIPickerView

Tags: swift, uipickerview

I've found some similar questions to this but none of the solutions matched my situation, and most were in objective-c which I don't know.

I'm trying to create a timer with minutes and seconds but I can't figure out how to wire up my second component.

**How do I set up a second component with a UIPickerView?**

This is what I have so far:

[image]

**TimeViewController.swift**

```
class TimeViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var timeSegueLabel: UILabel!

    let minutes = Array(0...9)
    let seconds = Array(0...59)

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {

        return 2
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

        return minutes.count

    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {

        return String(minutes[row])

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
}
```

Comment: Notice the UIPickerViewDataSource methods have a `component` parameter. You need to return a different number of rows or a different title for row depending on the section, so within these methods simply use an if statement or a switch to check the section.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Thanks to @Bluehound for pointing me in the right direction. I had to look at some [objective-c](https://github.com/AshRobinson/UIPickerView-Code/blob/master/UIPickerView%20Delegate) on GitHub to find out exactly how to do it, this is the answer I was looking for:

**TimeViewController:**

```
class TimeViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var timeSegueLabel: UILabel!

    let minutes = Array(0...9)
    let seconds = Array(0...59)

    var recievedString: String = ""

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {

        return 2

    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        //row = [repeatPickerView selectedRowInComponent:0];
        var row = pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(0)
        println("this is the pickerView\(row)")

        if component == 0 {
            return minutes.count
        }

        else {
            return seconds.count
        }

    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {

        if component == 0 {
        return String(minutes[row])
        } else {

        return String(seconds[row])
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        timeSegueLabel.text = recievedString

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }
```

**This is the result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Can do Picker with 2 components displaying in two labels**

**swift 4 xcode 9**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate,  UIPickerViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var lbl1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lbl2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var picker1: UIPickerView!

    var country = ["UK","US","JAPAN","UAE","CHINA","CANADA","EUROPE","IRAN","INDIA","ITALY" ]
    var capital = [ "LONDON","WASHIGTON DC","TOKYO","ABU DHABI","BEIJING","OTTAWA","BRUSSELS","TEHRAN","NEW DELHI","ROME" ]
    var val = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

        if component == 0 {
            return country.count
        } else {
            return capital.count
        }
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

        if component == 0 {
            return String(country[row])
        } else {
            return String(capital[row])
        }
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

        if component == 0 {
            lbl1.text = country[row]
        } else {
            lbl2.text = capital[row]
        }
    }
}
```