# Cannot convert return expression of type '[String]' to return type 'String?' / UIPickerView

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode8, uipickerview

I'm using a UIPickerView and its giving me the error (Cannot convert return expression of type '[String]' to return type 'String?' / UIPickerView). Here is my code.

```
// where the picker view is set up.
let cubesToWorkWith = ["3X3", "2X2", "4X4", "5X5", "6X6", "7X7", "Skewb", "Square-One"]
let threeByThreeArray = ["OLL", "PLL"]
@IBOutlet weak var pickerViewOutlet: UIPickerView!

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    let row = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
    print("this is the pickerView\(row)")

    switch row {
    case 0:
        return threeByThreeArray.count
    default:
        return cubesToWorkWith.count
    }
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    switch row {
    case 0:
        return threeByThreeArray[row]
    default:
        return getArrayForRow(row: row)
    }
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    cubeSelected = Int16(row)
}
func getArrayForRow(row: Int)  -> [String] {

    switch row {
    case 0:
        return threeByThreeArray
    default:
        return cubesToWorkWith
    }

  }
 } 
}
```

and I get the error at the switch case inside the titleForRow  at "return getArrayForRow(row: row)"
thanks for any help in advance!!!!

Comment: `getArrayForRow` returns `[String]` and `pickerView(_:titleForRow:…)` returns `String?`. What did you expected? Magic conversion between array and a string?

Comment: P.S. this is a follow up question from my other question Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42316756/uipickerview-multi-components-in-swift

Comment: `getArrayForRow(row: row)` returns an `Array`, but a `String?` is expected. I do not understand the expected output, but `getArrayForRow(row: row).first` will fix the crash and hopefully help you understand the issue :-)

Comment: You should not post the (wrong but accepted) answer to your original question as a new question. Instead write a comment to the answer of the original question to let the answerer know that it did not work out for you.

Comment: I added an answer to your original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you are missing a few things:

first, you need to set delegate ad Datasource to self
and in the `titleForRow`:

*you need to return a string so your:*

```
func getArrayForRow(row: Int)  -> [String]
```

*need to be like:*

```
func getArrayForRow(row: Int)  -> String
```

*here is my offer:*

```
class ViewController: UIViewController ,UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource{
// where the picker view is set up.
let cubesToWorkWith = ["3X3", "2X2", "4X4", "5X5", "6X6", "7X7", "Skewb", "Square-One"]
let threeByThreeArray = ["OLL", "PLL"]

@IBOutlet weak var pickerViewOutlet: UIPickerView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.pickerViewOutlet.dataSource = self
    self.pickerViewOutlet.delegate = self

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    let row = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
    print("this is the pickerView\(row)")

    switch row {
    case 0:
        return threeByThreeArray.count
    default:
        return cubesToWorkWith.count
    }
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    switch row {
    case 0:
        return threeByThreeArray[row] as String
    default:
        return getArrayForRow(row: row) as String
    }
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
   // cubeSelected = Int16(row)
}

func getArrayForRow(row: Int)  -> String {

    switch row {
    case 0:
        return threeByThreeArray[row]
    default:
        return cubesToWorkWith[row]
    }

}
```

}

Comment: ok so I changed this return threeByThreeArray to this return threeByThreeArray[row]