# Displaying second column in UIPickerView from JSON using what is picked from first column

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I have a JSON script that with the following structure:

```
[{"manufacturer”:”exampleManufacturer”,”model":"exampleModel”}]
```

I currently have the following UIPickerView set up that displays the first column `manufacturer`. **How can I display the second column `model` in the same UIPickerView?**

The second column is dependent on what is chosen for the first column, so it must reload.

The following is what I have so far to display the first column `manufacturer`:

```
import UIKit

class CreateRMA_ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {



        @IBOutlet weak var customerTextField: UITextField!


    var pickerView: UIPickerView!
    var values: [AnyObject] = []

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

        return self.values.count

    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {


        let titleRow = (values[row] as? String)!
        return titleRow


    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {


        if values.count > 0 && values.count >= row{
            self.customerTextField.text = self.values[row] as? String
            self.pickerView.isHidden = true
        }

    }




    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        //when you select the text field the picker view will be visible

        if(textField == self.customerTextField){
            self.pickerView.isHidden = false
            self.view.endEditing(true)
        }

    }



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }


        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            pickerView = UIPickerView()
            pickerView.dataSource = self
            pickerView.delegate = self


            //get the values from sql/Json
            let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.example.com/test/test.php")

            let data = NSData(contentsOf: url! as URL)
            var tmpValues = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data! as Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! NSArray
            tmpValues = tmpValues.reversed() as NSArray
            reloadInputViews()


            for candidate in tmpValues {
                if let cdict = candidate as? NSDictionary {

                    //fullName is the column name in sql/json
                    let names = cdict["customer"]
                    self.values.append(names! as AnyObject)


                }
            }
    }

}
```

**Sample of JSON:**

```
[{"manufacturer":"GE","model":"1147"},{"manufacturer":"GE","model":"34983"},{"manufacturer":"Apple","model":"8Plus"},{"manufacturer":"Samsung","model":"Galaxy 8"},{"manufacturer":"Samsung","model":"Note 5"},{"manufacturer":"Samsung","model":"Note 8"}]
```

Comment: For "How can I display the second column model in the same UIPickerView?"
You can return 2 in  numberOfComponentsInPickerView method.
But not getting this "The second column is dependent on what is chosen for the first column, so it must reload"?

Comment: @NikunjRajyaguru For example if my first column had “Fruits” and “Vegetables”. When selecting Fruits I expect my choices to be “Apple” and “Banana” not “Cucumber” and “Potato” in the second column

Comment: You should have a proper data structure for that

Comment: @RajeshKumarR  The data structure is in JSON

Comment: @RelsonJames, I don't think this can be achieved in a single UIPickerView, I would suggest you to use two different UIPickerViews i.e, one for the categories (Fruits, Vegetables, etc.) and another one for the subcategories.This way you can easily get your work done.

Comment: How can you display subcategories in a second uipickerview based on what is picked in the first. Can you please show me how this can be written?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I setup a second component with a UIPickerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29617835/how-do-i-setup-a-second-component-with-a-uipickerview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class TestViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    struct Category {
        var name: String
        var items: [String]
    }
    var allCategories = [Category]()
    var selectedCategory:Category?
    var selectedItem: String?

    var pickerView: UIPickerView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        allCategories = [Category(name: "Fruits", items: ["Apple","Banana"]), Category(name: "Vegetables", items: ["Cucumber","Potato"])]
        pickerView = UIPickerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 200, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 200))
        view.addSubview(pickerView)
        pickerView.dataSource = self
        pickerView.delegate = self


    }
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return selectedCategory == nil ? 1 : 2
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return component == 0 ? allCategories.count : selectedCategory?.items.count ?? 0
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if component == 0 {
            return allCategories[row].name
        } else {
            return selectedCategory?.items[row]
        }
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        if component == 0 {
            selectedCategory = allCategories[row]
            manufacturerTextField.text = allCategories[row].name
            pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
        } else {
            selectedItem = selectedCategory?.items[row]
            modelTextField.text = selectedCategory?.items[row]
        }
    }

}
```

**Edit**

```
if let url = URL(string: "https://www.example.com/test/test.php"),
    let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url),
    let tmpValues = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [[String:String]] {
    let tempCategories = tmpValues?.reduce(into: [String:[String]](), { (dict, value) in
        if let manufacturer = value["manufacturer"], let model = value["model"] {
            dict[manufacturer, default:[]].append(model)
        }
    })
    for category in (tempCategories ?? [:]) {
        allCategories.append(Category(name: category.key, items: category.value))
    }
    pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please modify this to work with my code, I don't have much experience with Swift and UIPickerView. I will mark your answer as correct

Comment: @RelsonJames I don't know what do you get in your api response. You have to change the Category struct according to your api response

Comment: My api response looks like this: [{"manufacturer”:”exampleManufacturer”,”model":"exampleModel”}]

Comment: Different exampleManufacturer will have different exampleModel

Comment: @RelsonJames So exampleManufacturer can contain 1 or more models?

Comment: Yes that's correct, please look at how I have it written currently

Comment: @RelsonJames post sample json with multiple models

Comment: Does that help?

Comment: Would that go in the viewdidload?

Comment: @RelsonJames yes

Comment: I really appreciate your help..My only question now is how can I make the  selections made to show in a textfield. I would like the first column (manufacturer) to show in a textfield called manufacturerTextField and the right column to show in a textfield called modelTextField

Comment: @RelsonJames Check updated pickerView didSelectRow method

Comment: Can you please take a look at my recent question? It builds upon this question, by adding a second text field, I tried to do it myself but ran into an issue.

Answer (score 0):

For 2 columns in pikcerview use 2 in numberOfComponentsInPickerView.

You can follow this answer.

[How do I setup a second component with a UIPickerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29617835/how-do-i-setup-a-second-component-with-a-uipickerview)

Comment: How can I make the second column dependent of the first one? For example if my first column had “Fruits” and “Vegetables”. When selecting Fruits I expect my choices to be “Apple” and “Banana” not “Cucumber” and “Potato”

Comment: on choose fist column value reload second column data, based on first column value